# iframe showing different src value

Tags: jquery, asp.net, iframe

I've an issue in my web application with ifram I need to check if the iframe src is empty or not but my current code gives me different values means if the iframe is actually empty the src gives the url of the web page my current code is given below

**HTML**

```
<iframe src="" id="frmImage1" frameborder="0" style="height: 410px; width: 100%; margin-top: 10px; overflow: hidden" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

**Jquery**

```
 var value1 = $("#frmImage1")[0].src;
```

the expected value of value1 is **" "** but I'm getting the sites url what is the problem with the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code to get src of iframe.

```
alert($('#frmImage1').contents().get(0).location.href);
```

Comment: its worked... and what about setting the iframe src $("#frmImage1")[0].src=""; is not working for me

Answer (score 0):

if `src=""` or `src="#"`, you will get the url of current page.
You can remove the `src=""` and you will get empty.